# How to get total star of a particular post type

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.8

I have different post types that users can post review under for example:-

Post types:-

1. Cars
2. TV

**User 1:-** writes a review under the post type of cars and give it 5 stars.

**User 2:-** also writes a review under same post type giving star of 3 etc

**User 3:-** Writes a review under Tv and give a star of 3 etc

I like to get average stars of post type of Cars and display under post type of cars and also average stars of Tv and display under Tv. Does anyone have any idea on how to get the correct total stars?  any suggestion will be helpful

I have tried by getting the posts under all post type then loop through to get the star rating but it seems to get back all the total stars as oppose to getting the total stars under each post type if that make sense

```
     $getposttypes  = Posttype::Join('categories','posttypes.category_id','=','categories.id')
      ->select('posttypes.id','posttypes.name','posttypes.slug','categories.name as categoryname','posttypes.created_at','posttypes.updated_at')->get();

      foreach ($getposttypes as $key) {
        $posts []=Post::Where('posttype_id',$key['id'])->get();
        foreach ($posts as $postkey) {
          foreach ($postkey as $keyval) {
            if($keyval['posttype_id'] ==$key['id']){
              $poststars [] = $keyval['rating'];
            }
          }
        }
      }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the Query Which might help you.

Assumed from your explanation that. "Posttype" contain "Cars" & "TV".
& "Post" contain all the ratings.

Create post function in Posttype Model

```
function post() {
    return $this->hasMany(Post::class, 'posttype_id', 'id');
}
```

& Write this Query to get your result of average with each post type.

```
$post_types = Posttype::with(['post' => function($query){
    $query->avg('rating');
}])->get();
```

Let me know if you find any issue with this solution.

Comment: Hi Vishal, Thanks for getting back to me, I will give this a go and let you know how I get on

Comment: Do I have to add a function in the post model as well? because currently my post model has  a function "return $this->hasMany('App\Posttype')" and Posttype model has a function "return $this->belongsTo('App\Post');"

Comment: Hi Vishal, I was able to get it working using your idea.  my solution:- $posts_type = Post::Where('posttype_id',$key['id'])->With('posttype')->get();
 $totalstars[] = $posts_type->avg('rating');

Comment: Great! Good to know it helped!